# Python 'set' object does not support indexing

Tags: indexing, append, typeerror

I am working on a Windows 7 os in a Python (3.2.2) shell.  Trying to learn the language I entered and had returned the following:

```
>>> cast = {
    'cleese',
    'Palin',
    'Jones',
    'Idle'
    }
>>> print (cast[1])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#12>", line 1, in <module>
    print (cast[1])
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
>>> cast.append('Gilliam')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#13>", line 1, in <module>
    cast.append('Gilliam')
AttributeError: 'set' object has no attribute 'append'
```

==========================

It seems as if the problem is not in the coding, but with how the program was installed.

I have installed, un-installed and installed again, but the resutl is the same.  I there something I need to do before Python's shell is ready to be used?

hans

Comment: Is what you've posted here the complete code? It looks like you're defining a dict and then trying to access it using list notation. You should be seeing a syntax error here. Try cast = ["cleese","Palin","Jones","Idle"]. Notice the '[' instead of '{'

Answer (score 20):

Python seems to work fine. The point is that `set` doesn't support indexing or appending. Try using a list instead (`[]` instead of `{}`). In place of appending, `set` has `add`, but indexing is out.

And Python has useful help,

```
>>> help(set)
```

prints a lot of info about `set`s.

Answer (score 4):

It seems that you were trying to define a list. However, you used braces {} instead of brackets []. The interpreter treated it as a dictionary rather than a list, so indexing and append() didn't work here.

Comment: As stated in the old answer, the interpreter treats `cast` as a set, not a dictionary. There are no key/value pairs to form a dict.

Answer (score 3):

Just to mention in here, `set's'` do not support indexing, as they are hash based, it is very similar to `dictionaries` which don't support indexing as well. You can only access a `dict` by it's `key`.

If you need indexing, you can convert your set as follows:

```
convertedToList = list(set(1,2,3))
```

Comment: I hate python. Of course any reasonable person wants to iterate over a set.